# What does means 'indiscriminate' in RF systems

Tags: rf

The RWS-371 RF modules work as at the 434 MHz  band, the documentations states: "These modules are indiscriminate and will receive a fair amount of noise".I guess they at least have some kind of bandpass filter, so what does 'indiscriminate' means? How does this compares with the RF24L01 were you need to specify and pipe address?.

Comment: In practical terms it means they are extremely primitive in comparison to the NRF24L01 type radios - your software will have to do a lot more itself to frame data and determine its validity, and even then the capability and performance will be lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more 'radio' terms, that means they lack selectivity.

An indiscriminate, unselective radio will often stop working if there is a strong signal present outside its bandwidth. This is known as 'blocking'. With mobile comms masts all over the place, you can find strong interfering signals everywhere.